# No master listed as git repo

Tags: git

I'm a newb trying to merge my tagged local development branch to my remote master with the following (Note: these are dummy names for clarity):

```
> git checkout master
> git merge --no-ff development
> git push origin master
> git tag -a v2.0 -m "New production code."
```

But

```
> git checkout master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I've done `git fetch --all` but nothing is returned to console.

Trying

```
> git branch -a
* development
```

[image: screen grab of git branch -a]
EDIT: This is the complete output for `git branch -a`

Where has my `master` gone? I've been pushing changes to it and can see it in my remote GitLab repo.

Using git version 2.14.2.windows.3

EDIT: Output from `git reflog` with real names from my repo

```
$ git reflog
f200462 (HEAD -> naei17dev) HEAD@{0}: commit: Updated
703ef7e HEAD@{1}: commit: Update
144ecdb HEAD@{2}: commit: Initial commit
0992345 HEAD@{3}: commit: Not needed
580e25e HEAD@{4}: commit: Added as variables for checking
594f3ed HEAD@{5}: commit: Fiel system path change
15282a5 HEAD@{6}: commit: Added parameter file
af1846f HEAD@{7}: commit: Re-instated
f99d440 HEAD@{8}: commit: Added parameters file
0ee8227 HEAD@{9}: commit: Update tailoring for changed downloaded data format.
a558bd6 HEAD@{10}: commit: Revision for this year's data.
e55c2b7 HEAD@{11}: commit: Update tailoring to changed downloaded data format.Re                                                                                                                vised record check.
b25490b HEAD@{12}: commit: Change England-Wales record check
b6a2f95 HEAD@{13}: commit: Add unzip function. Tailor code to changed downloaded                                                                                                                 data format.
ca129a3 HEAD@{14}: commit: Update sources
80e0a8c HEAD@{15}: commit: New NAEI year run
6cb8107 HEAD@{16}: commit: Removed
0348715 (tag: naei2016) HEAD@{17}: checkout: moving from 03487159e1f1b61efcb0587                                                                                                                cfc2c59f125e2451a to naei17dev
0348715 (tag: naei2016) HEAD@{18}: clone: from git@git.<CONFIDENTIAL>/                                                                                                                population-distribution.git
```

Comment: Can you show the complete output for `git branch -a` as it doesn't show the remote branches either?

Comment: no master is showing up. The branch was deleted, perhaps? It would be no reason to fear but still. Check `git reflog` to find the last revision you created there and create master again pointing to that revision.

Comment: What happens when you run `$ git fetch` (download all references from the remote), and then `$ git branch -a` again? If there's a remote branch `master`, but no `remotes/origin/master` in the output of `$ git branch -a` after fetching, that would be unusual.

Comment: @evolutionxbox that is complete output ... `* development`

Comment: @mark your remote is gone? Try adding it again `git remote add origin git@git.ricardo-aea.com:naei-gis/...` (whatever the correct url is)

Comment: @JakeWorth ran fetch again - output of `git branch -a` same as in OP.

Comment: @evolutionxbox tried to add remote - get `fatal: remote origin already exists.`

Comment: @eftshift0 reflog added to OP. Remote master is present in my GitLab repo. Do you mean it's been deleted locally? Why isn't fetch doing its job?

Comment: Then you should be seeing remote branches in `git branch -a` output? 
 `* development
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/development`

Comment: If the branch has been deleted locally, try checking the remote one out? `git checkout origin/master && git branch master`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193152/discussion-between-mark-and-evolutionxbox).

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: trashed local repo, `git clone` from remote, `git merge` and `git push` worked fine. Git must have 'broken' somewhere along the line.